# SQL Query not working, inner join

Tags: sql

the SQL query below wont work for me. I've tried everything can someone please help?

```
     SELECT u.user_login, s.Email FROM users u INNER JOIN form f ON f.StudentID = s.StudentID 
INNER JOIN student s ON s.StudentID = s.StudentID WHERE f.form_id = 188
```

Thanks You!

Comment: What fields do you have in your table? 
From your SQL query I can say that you misuse join's ON clause: 
1) f.StudentID = s.StudentID: s table has not been introduced yet; 
2) s.StudentID = s.StudentID: makes no sense; 
3) your user table is not connected with joined tables

Comment: "Not working" is not a valid problem description.  **What** isn't working - too many results?  Not enough results?  Unexpected results?  Or just the stated syntax error?  Be specific.  As a side note, it's usually best to put _all_ conditions of a `JOIN` into the accompanying `ON` clause; for some other types of joins, there _is_ a semantic difference, but most people it's _not_ the one they really want.  Note that your optimizer is probably re-writing it silently for you anyways (or would, if you didn't have a syntax error)?

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
 SELECT u.user_login, s.Email
 FROM users u INNER JOIN
      form f
      ON f.StudentID = s.StudentID INNER JOIN
-----------------------^
      student s
      ON s.StudentID = s.StudentID
 WHERE f.form_id = 188;
```

The highlighted expression is a syntax error, because the table alias `s` is not yet defined.  A `from` statement reads from the beginning to the end, sequentially.  Perhaps you mean something like this:

```
 SELECT u.user_login, s.Email
 FROM users u INNER JOIN
      student s
      on s.UserId = u.UserId INNER JOIN
      form f
      ON f.StudentID = s.StudentID
 WHERE f.form_id = 188;
```

I am just guessing on the proper relationship between the tables.

Comment: Simply reformatting the SQL query well makes things like much easier to solve.

Comment: Needs another "INNER JOIN" before the "form f"